# Amazon API to search product in several categories?

Tags: amazon-product-api

How can I search product in several categories by product name 
using amazon API?

I tried to use this
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html , but not sure if there is a way to put several category ids in request?